# Acts_as_tenant ruby gem. Specific user login without tenant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant

I am using Acts_as_tenant gem in my RoR application. In every user login, the gem first review that the user has a tenant and the current tenant is consulted by the current subdomain. 
But now I need to login a specific user that doesn't have tenant. What can I do?

Comment: `config.require_tenant = false`

Comment: I guess you use `set_current_tenant_by_subdomain` from `acts_as_tenant` gem. It doesn't restrict users without subdomain. I guess the restriction should be somewhere in your controller filters. Paste the code of the filter and we will help you.

Comment: `ActsAsTenant.with_tenant(nil) { .. login code here .. }`

Answer (score 0):

```
ActsAsTenant.without_tenant do { .. Your code .. }
```

Use `ActsAsTenant.without_tenant` wherever you want to ignore the default tenant setup.